# Test case failing: ClassCastException: androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel$Subclass1 cannot be cast to class SecondChildViewModel

Tags: android, unit-testing, viewmodel, android-testing, robolectric

Having parent and child Activities & viewModels. My assumption is always taking parent viewmodel and not able to take child viewModel. so that my test cases are failing.

viewModels are like

- FirstSecondChildCancellationViewModel -> ParentViewModel
- SecondChildCancellationViewModel -> ParentViewModel

Activities are as follows:

- FirstChildCancellationActivity -> ParentActivity
- SecondChildCancellationActivity -> ParentActivity

  ```
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        binding = mockk()
        val intent = Intent()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelable(EXTRA_HEADER_LAYOUT, myCancelModel)
        intent.putExtras(bundle)

        subjectController = Robolectric.buildActivity(
            SecondChildCancellationActivity::class.java, intent
        ).create() // Test case failing, error pasted below

        subject = subjectController.get()

        mockkStatic(ViewModelProviders::class)
        val mockViewModelProvider = mockkClass(ViewModelProvider::class)
        every { ViewModelProviders.of(any<FragmentActivity>(), any()) } returns mockViewModelProvider
        every { mockViewModelProvider.get(any<Class<SecondChildCancellationViewModel>>()) } returns mockViewModel

    }
  ```

My Testcase:

```
    @Test
    fun `verify onCreate init is happening and status is displaying in header`() {

        subjectController.visible().get()

        assert(subject.cancelId).isEqualTo(myCancelModel.cancelId)
        assert(binding.statusTextView.status).isEqualTo(myCancelModel.statusText)
    }
```

Getting Error on my testcase:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel$Subclass1 cannot be cast to class com.company.project.cancellation.SecondChildCancellationViewModel (androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel$Subclass1 and com.company.project.cancellation.SecondChildCancellationViewModel are in unnamed module of loader org.robolectric.internal.AndroidSandbox$SdkSandboxClassLoader @12e24679)
    at com.company.project.cancellation.SecondChildCancellationActivity.retrieveViewModel(SecondChildCancellationActivity.kt:47)
```